# How many different color combinations (red-black-black-red-red-black) are possible in a deck of cards?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have regular deck of playing cards and I want to find out how many color combinations there are in the deck. The cards fall into two categories: red and black. Here are the givens.
Total $52$ items;
$2$ distinct, repetition;
$26$ black;
$26$ red;
Cards like $7$ of diamonds and king of hearts are red, while cards like the ace of spades and jack of clubs are black.

Comment: You won't get any answers unless you show what you've already did. This isn't somewhere to go post your homework problems.

Comment: This isn't a homework problem. I'm just curious of what it would be and if there is a formula of it.

Comment: Are you asking how many sequences of red and black cards there are or how many times the pattern red-black-black-red-red-black can appear in the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Just focus on one color (say, red), and think about the position of the 26 red cards in the deck (positions range from 1 to 52). That is, the red cards take up 26 of the 52 possible positions ... so how many sets of 26 numbers out of 1 through 52 are there?

Comment: I'm a little confused in what you mean by how many sets of 26 numbers out of 1-52 are there.

Comment: OK, suppose the first 26 cards are all red.  Then they take up positions 1 through 26.  So this would correspond to the set $\{ 1,2,3,..., 26 \}$.  Now suppose the first 25 cards are all red, and also the very last one.  That would correspond to the set $\{ 1,2,3,..., 25, 52 \}$.  And if every second card is red, we get the set $\{ 2,4,6,...,48,50,52 \}$.  In other words, every color combination corresponds to a selection of 26 numbers out of the numbers 1 through 52.

Comment: I understand. This would be a very big number. Impossible to count. What method can we use to get this number? Factorial? If so, I know we can't just use 26! I'm stuck here not knowing what to do.

Comment: @TH3F145H Yes, a very big number indeed! OK, so what I had hoped my HINT would point you towards is the 'choose' function ... if you are unfamiliar with that function, look it up.

Comment: Is it C (52, 26)?

Comment: @TH3F145H You got it!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @TH3F145H You're welcome!  :) Since you are new: please know that you can accept my answer by checking the checkmark on the left.